# Рисование пазлов

Tags: android, разработка-игр, canvas, graphics

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать программирование с написания Паззлов - аналога обычных картонных. Нужен совет, в каком направлении двигать булки. В данный момент реализовал рисование на канве кругов и их перетаскивание, выглядит это так:

```
public class GameWindow extends Activity{

private GraphicsView myView;
private int selDot = -1;
private int imgInd;

private class GraphicsView extends View{
    //Класс, реализущий перетаскиваемую точку
    private class Dot {
        float dotX, dotY;
        Paint dotPaint;
    }

    private Dot[] arrDots;
    private final int dflColor = Color.YELLOW;
    private int Rad = 20;
    private float initialX, initialY,
                  offsetX, offsetY;

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        //Рисуем пять точек с произвольными координатами
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int i;          
        arrDots = new Dot[5];
        for (i=0; i<5; i++){
            arrDots[i] = new Dot();
            arrDots[i].dotX = rnd.nextInt(400);
            arrDots[i].dotY = rnd.nextInt(400);
            arrDots[i].dotPaint = new Paint();
            arrDots[i].dotPaint.setColor(dflColor);
        }

        //Собственно обработчик перетаскивания точки
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                       float posX = event.getX();
                       float posY = event.getY();

                       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                           if (posX > (arrDots[i].dotX - Rad) &&
                               posX < (arrDots[i].dotX + Rad) &&
                               posY > (arrDots[i].dotY - Rad) &&
                               posY < (arrDots[i].dotY + Rad)){
                               initialX = arrDots[i].dotX;
                               initialY = arrDots[i].dotY;
                               offsetX = posX;
                               offsetY = posY;
                               arrDots[i].dotPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                               selDot = i;
                           }
                           else
                               arrDots[i].dotPaint.setColor(dflColor);
                       }
                   break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                       if (selDot >= 0){                               
                           arrDots[selDot].dotX = event.getX() + 
                                                  initialX - offsetX;
                           arrDots[selDot].dotY = event.getY() + 
                                                  initialY - offsetY;
                       }
                   break;
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                           arrDots[i].dotPaint.setColor(dflColor);
                       selDot = -1;
                   break;        
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                   break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    //Перерисовываем точки на канве
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            canvas.drawCircle(arrDots[i].dotX, arrDots[i].dotY, Rad,
                              arrDots[i].dotPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myView = new GraphicsView(this);
    myView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    ll.addView(myView);
    setContentView(ll);
}}
```

По всему этому имею несколько вопросов, просьба откликнуться действительно разбирающихся людей ))) Интересует даже не столько пример, сколько общий принцип реализации, т.е. в каком направлении копать.

1. Как вырезать из Bitmap-а кусок произвольной формы и реализовать их склеивание при соприкосновении? Я думаю, делать это с помощью класса Path, но в гугле ничего конкретного не нашел, может плохо гуглил.
2. Никогда не работал с OpenGL, может быть с помощью нее можно сделать все проще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Надо определиться с тем насколько возможно склеивание, т.е. мы всегда знаем от чего отрезан кусок пузла и с какими кусками он связан, или мы знаем КАК он отрезан и его можно связать с такими же кусками если они ТАК ЖЕ вырезаны не зависимо - верно это или нет.
2. Визуально, сложный обрез обычно делается транспарентом, можно скажем определить набор вырезных шаблонных картинок и вычитать из картинки этот шаблон.
3. Open GL имеет смысл использовать если нужно 3d, в 2в варианте Android предоставляет удобное апи. Плюс проще работать с битмапами.

Попозже напишу больше

Comment: А-а-а... т.е., чтобы разрезать картинку - создаем несколько шаблонов, для каждого определяем список подходящих по форме шаблонов, причем подходить шаблон к шаблону может слева, а справа нет и т.д. А потом, начиная, скажем, с угла режем картинку, каждый раз выбирая рандомный шаблон из списка подходящих к текущему. Правильно понял?

Если можно поподробнее про транспарант.

Comment: 1.Да. Про транспарент идея такая - есть шаблон обреза - внутренняя часть шаблона рисуем прозрачным цветом, внешнюю белым например рисуем на кусок картинки, потом заменяем белый фон на прозрачный - в итого получим битмап обрезаный

Comment: Под шаблоном обреза имеется ввиду объект класса Paint?

Comment: Да можно использовать обычный Bitmap, там надо покопаться скорее всего есть более нужный класс.